# getting "ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir ....." error on installing express in angular CLI app.

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-cli, mean-stack

I am creating my first MEAN app. I have installed angular CLI and also tested it using `ng serve -o` this command then i build app using `ng build` which also succeeded.

Now when I am trying to install "express" and "body-parser" I am getting following error

```
ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/media/iconflux/DATA/vinit/Mean/meanApp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/dashdash/node_modules/assert-plus'
```

I checked the directory it is empty. I also tried manually deleting the directory but still no success.

Here is the command i am using to install express and body-parser

```
npm install --save express body-parser
```

Note: I am working on ubuntu 14.0

Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: try `npm cache clean` before installing.

Comment: @AmitChigadani it dosen't worked.. still getting same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this command : `npm install --save express body-parser --force`